# mvc2 with ajax table enabling back button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, browser-history, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have created my application that has search form and below contains results for the search.
Now i want to be able to add history, button back functionality.

The problem is i am caught in infinitive loop of loading page and i am not sure why, this is in FireFox.

I have followed this tutorial how to do this:

> http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs

My code is:

**Javascript**

```
 <% =Html.JQuery() %>
 <script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var _currentCaseId = -1;
    Sys.Application.add_init(pageInit);
        function OnBegin() {
            var caseId =  $("#SelectDeceased_hidden").val();

            Sys.Application.addHistoryPoint({ "caseId": caseId });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#divTableContainer").html("");
            });
        }

        function OnSuccess() {
            $('#divTableContainer').fadeIn('slow');
        }

        function OnFailure() {
            alert("Something went wrong. Try again...");
        }

    function pageInit() {
        // Enable history
        Sys.Application.set_enableHistory(true);

        // Add Handler for history
        Sys.Application.add_navigate(navigate);
    }

    function navigate(sender, e) {
        // Get groupId from address bar
        var caseId = e.get_state().caseId;

        // if cases does not match
        if (_currentCaseId != caseId) {
            // assign the case id
            _currentCaseId = caseId;
            alert(caseId);
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/PostItems/UmiTable?currentCase=" 
                                             + _currentCaseId 
                                             + "&EntityType=-1",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#divContactList").text(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

**And my html**

```
  <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("UmiTable", new AjaxOptions() { 
                                       OnFailure = "OnFailure", 
                                       OnBegin = "OnBegin", 
                                       LoadingElementId = "divLoading", 
                                       UpdateTargetId = "divTableContainer" })) %>
  <% { %>
  <% using (Html.MooseFieldWrapper("Find case", "StandardForm"))
       {  %>             
            <%= Html.CutomTextBox("Case") %>                
           <li class="Button"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></li>
    <% } %>
  <% } %>
 <div id="divLoading">     
     <div><img src="Indicator.gif" alt="loading data" />Loading</div>
 </div>
 <div id="divTableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in MicrosoftAjax as the code works fine in IE and Chrome. It's an obsolete library anyway. Is there any reason you are still using it instead of jQuery (which by the way I see that you have referenced, so why not take advantage of it)? Also now that there's HTML5 history capabilities built into modern browsers it would be pity not to take advantage of them. For example the excellent [jquery.history](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) plugin does that and degrades gracefully to the old method (using an url fragment) in legacy browsers that do not support the API.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I have seen this solution so i thought i will not use jquery but use microsoft ajax dlls.

Comment: well, I am afraid you thought wrong.

Comment: Thanks for help anyway. at least i know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end
i have used jquery history script to manage navigation.